# Limit of something that does not depend on x at all?

Tags: limits

A simple example would be $x/x$. Clearly the $x's$ just cancel out and we are left with $1$, so is the limit for $x \rightarrow whatever$ always 1?

Or, more generally, is the limit of $f(z)$ as $x \rightarrow a$ just $f(z)$?

Not sure what to do.

Comment: yes, just think to the graphic of such a function..
It's constant in $x$

Comment: It certainly does not depend on $x$, $x$ is just a variable. it may or may not depend on that you call $whatever$, depending on whether the  function is continuous or not. By the same token the answer to your second question is no.

Comment: The "whatever" is just a number,0 for example, not a variable. What then?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(z)$ can factored out as a constant because $f(z)$ does not depend on $x$. Therefore,
$$ \lim_{x\to a} f(z)=f(z)\left[\lim_{x\to a} 1\right]=f(z) $$